# Stored Procedure not updating Null field

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have a textfield and button set up to trim the end of a youtube link and save it to a SQL Server table. But my stored procedure isn't actually saving anything.

**HTML**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtYoutubeLink" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Width="300"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save Link" Width="120" />
```

**VB.Net**

```
 Protected Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        If txtYoutubeLink.Text = "" Then
        Else

            Dim link As String = txtYoutubeLink.Text
            Dim shortlink As String = link.Substring(link.LastIndexOf("=") + 1)

            SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("dbConn"), "X_WW_spSaveVideoUrl", lstStockItems.SelectedItem.Value.ToString(), shortlink)
        End If
    End Sub
```

**Stored procedure**:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[X_WW_spSaveVideoUrl]
     @STOCKCODE VARCHAR(15),
     @VideoURL VARCHAR(max)
AS
    UPDATE Stock_Items 
    SET X_VIDEOURL = @VideoURL
    WHERE StockCode = @STOCKCODE
```

`lstStockItems` is a ASP:Datalist set by another stored procedure, the value field has been correctly set to be product stock codes. It's in use on several pages so I know that's not where it's failing, but I can't see why the new procedure isn't working. The only thing I can think of is that this is being used to overwrite `null` fields in an existing Table, so maybe my update query is wrong?

**Edit**

Here is another textbox/button combo that I use to change the youtube link for products that already have one listed against them.

```
Protected Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
        If txtChangeYoutubeLink.Text = "" Then
        Else
            Dim link As String = txtChangeYoutubeLink.Text
            Dim shortlink As String = link.Substring(link.LastIndexOf("=") + 1)
            SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("dbConn"), "X_WW_spSaveVideoUrl", lstLinked.SelectedItem.Value.ToString(), shortlink)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Works fine. So, I can use the procedure to change the `X_VideoUrl` field from "blah" to "bleh" but can't change it from NULL to "bleh".

Comment: Have you debug your code? Have you try to see what values stored in shortlink and lstStockItems.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() and what value you are passing? may be you are passing values in wrong sequence.

Comment: The Youtube link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q03nIupGAIQ is correctly shortened to Q03nIupGAIQ, but not sent to the SQL Table. I also double checked that it was getting the right list Item value.

Comment: Show this method/signature.. `SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("dbConn"), "X_WW_spSaveVideoUrl", lstStockItems.SelectedItem.Value.ToString(), shortlink)`. I can almost be it this as the arguments you are passing isnt usually the way to do it unless you have created this method... Also those are not sql parameters, I dont know you would even compile that.

Comment: @Codexer this was pre-exisiting in the site's Webconfig before I got the job. It's used for any calls to the SQL server. Everything up tp `("dbConn")` just accesses the right server, `"X_WW_spSaveVideoUrl"` is the name of the stored procedure and then everything after that are the procedure parameters in order of declaration in SQL, It's used at least 150 times across the site, and someone who knows more than me set it up, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: You have to send in parameters not just strings to a sql instance

Comment: Hover over executenonquery and post the signature. Tell me what it takes, in ex: the type of objects. Or right click and Go To Definition.

Comment: `Public Shared Overloads Function ExecuteNonQuery(connectionString as String, spName as String, ParamArray parameterValues() as Object) as Integer.`

This really shouldn't be the problem, as I use the SqlHelper three other times on this same page to retrieve stock codes and product categories with not trouble.

Comment: Also, the Stored Procedure in question works when used on an update button to overwrite existing values, it just borks when I'm trying to overwrite a null value.

Comment: Can you exec the proc in a query and see if it works? What about running SQL profiler when you hit the button and see exactly what SQL is being generated?

Answer (score 0):

When you save any string in database table using SP then you should write with single Quote like `'"++"'` . You pass your variable value in this way.

You can do changes like this.    `SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("dbConn"), '"X_WW_spSaveVideoUrl"', lstLinked.SelectedItem.Value.ToString(), shortlink)`

**Or**

```
Dim URL as string = "www.youtube.com"
SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("dbConn"), '"+ URL +"', lstLinked.SelectedItem.Value.ToString(), shortlink)
```

Comment: The string after `("dbConn")` is not the string being saved to the Table. It's the name of the stored procedure and works with just the double quote marks. It's a standard part of this website's code, it's more the SQL procedure itself I'm wondering about since it works in one case but not another?

Comment: Which part of the code do you want to see? I've posted everything to do with this situation, the rest of the page involves layout and another couple of buttons doing different functions. The SQLHelper line itself is not the problem as it's a line used at least 100 times throughout the site.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a work-around. After jiggling, prodding, cursing and being angry at my code, I just crossed my fingers and ran an update query in Server Manager. Updated the column for 35,000 stock items, changing *NULL* to 0.

The query I made had no trouble changing the field from 0 to whatever I wanted, so I stopped messing with the null fields and just made sure the default value on the column is 0 to cover new stock items.

Works fine now.

Comment: That's an interesting article, I always kind thought that NULL was more trouble than it's worth. I still think it's weird that I could change from 0 to 1 but not from null to 1.